# angular2 typescript $.cookie() is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, cookies

I installed @types/jquery.cookie@1.4.28, then in tsconfig.json I added jquery.cookie in types section. Visual Studio Code shows that $.cookie is available to use, but when I run my code I get error in console that $.cookie() is not a function. Where is the problem? Am I missing something? Should I reference it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the `jquery.cookie` package in your code? Or just the `@types/jquery.cookie@1.4.28`?

`@types` are just definition files for TypeScript, not the actual code it self. So we still need to install the code it self:

```
npm install --save jquery.cookie
```

Then add it to your packaging, for instance for SystemJS:

```
SystemJS.config({
    'map': {
        'jquery.cookie': 'npm:jquery.cookie'
    },
    'paths': {
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    }
});
```

To sum up:

- `@types` are definitions to allow TypeScript understand code/packages written in JavaScript (as most of them are or at least compiled to). `@types` shouldn't be imported in the code it self. Only installed, the TypeScript compiler automatically looks for all defintions in `node_modules/@types`.
- The package you want to use with TypeScript still needs to be installed with `npm` (or `yarn`). These hold the actual code.

Comment: I tried to import it in app.module.ts like this: "import '@types/jquery.cookie';"
but when I compile code it throws error that couldn't find module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :)